# Is there any way to group edit buttons in MediaWiki?

Tags: button, editor, grouping, mediawiki

Is there any way to group the edit buttons displayed above the edit dialog in MediaWiki?  By grouping, I mean like Word does (and even this editor) - you can add **dividing lines** to group them so that e.g. Bold and Italic are in one group, numbered list and bullet points in another.

We've added lots of new buttons (in `EditPage.php`) and they are in a logical order, but at 30 buttons it is a bit overwhelming for some users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you make some fake buttons that don't do anything, but look like dividing lines? Would that work for you?

Comment: Yeah, this is a clever idea.  I'll try it out and get back to you.

Comment: This works, great.  Now I've got to work out how to make the dividing buttons smaller, specifically narrower.  Any ideas?  If not I'll post another question.

Here's the code I used from EditPage.php:

   array( 'image' => "button_divider.png",
    'id'    => "button_divider",
    'tip' => "divider (not for editing)",
    'open' => '',
    'close' => '',
    'sample'=> ''
   ),

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out [wikEd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Cacycle/wikEd), it seems to organize the buttons pretty well, if you can see the code it could help you maybe.

Comment: Appreciate the reply, thanks.  Problem is, wikEd is a *new* editor function and I'm looking to group the *existing* buttons.

BTW - we also use wikEd (optionally - only client installation).

Comment: Which version of mediawiki are you using? On the newer version they have changed the way the buttons look, and on the older versions there doesn't seem to be any diving lines between the buttons.

Comment: Currently 1.13.2 but we hope to upgrade to latest & greatest soon.